# Algorithm to enumerate paths

Tags: algorithm, counting

Say you are standing at point 0 on the real line. At each step, you can either move to the left l places, or to the right r places. You intend to get to the number p. Also, there are some numbers on which you are not allowed to step. You want count in how many you can do this. All numbers mentioned are integers (l and r positive, of course). What would be a good method for counting this?

Note. You can step on p itself in the journey as well, so the answer is infinity in some cases.

Comment: if at point 0 r = 3, could you walk to 1, 2, 3 or only walk to 3 ?

Comment: You have to go directly to r = 3.

Comment: what if there is a loop, e.g. at 0 r = 3, at 3 l = 3? In fact if there are two ways of getting to the finish line, there must be a loop

Comment: If you are allowed to step on every number, this is easy since the answer will then either be zero or infinity. (Depending on whether the greatest common divisor of l and r divides p).

Comment: @robert: l and r are fixed throughout the journey. And the answer can be infinity.

Comment: right, i thought at each point l and r are given to you lol

Comment: Sounds like standard graph pathfinding.  Have you tried to see how a breadth-first search fits the problem?

Comment: Hm .. I haven't, but there are an infinity of vertices. Note that you can keep moving even after reaching p.

Comment: @NN Infinite vertices is not a problem. :)  Breath-first search will also halt after finding the shortest path.

Comment: Ultimately, you are looking for (subsets of) solutions to al + br = p for non-negative integers a and b.  That might get you started.

Comment: If you step left `r/gcd(l,r)` times, and right `l/gcd(l,r)` times , in any order, you get back to the starting -point. So there would be infinitly many or zero paths to almost all destinations.

Answer (score 0):

It just like "how many integer(x,y) solutions with L*x+R*y=P".

I believe there are numbers of articles to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an algorithmic question but rather a math question. Nevertheless, here is the solution. Let us assume that your numbers `l` and `r` are positive integers (none of them are zero).

A solution exists if, and only if, the equation `r * x - l * y = p` has nonnegative integer solutions `(x, y)`. The equation expresses the fact that we walked `x` times to the right and `y` times to the left, in any order. The equation is known as [Bézout identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) and we know precisely what its solutions look like.

If `gcd(r,l)` divides `p` then there exists an integer solution `(x0, y0)`, and every other solution is of the form `x = x0 + k * r / gcd(l,r)`, `y = y0 + k * l / gcd(l,r)` where `k` runs through the integers. Clearly, if `k` is larger than both `-x0 * gcd(l,r) / r` and `-y0 * gcd(l,r) / l` then `x` and `y` are nonnegative, so we have infinitely many solutions.

If `gcd(r,l)` does not divide `p` then there are no solutions because the left hand side is always divisible by `gcd(l,r)` but the right-hand side is not.

In summary, your algorithm for counting the solutions looks like this:

```
if p % gcd(l,r):
    return Infinity
else:
    return 0
```

At this point it seems pointless to try to enumerate all the paths, because that will be a rather boring exercise. For each nonnegative solution `(x,y)` we simply enumerate all possible ways of arranging `x` moves to the right and `y` moves to the left. There will be   `(x+y)!/(x! * y!)` such paths (among the `x+y` steps pick `x` which will be the moves to the right).